# how can i view all the user with type of access level they have?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I can see all users with there title and department, by following this link

`https://sitename /_catalogs/users/simple.aspx`.

Is there any way if i want to see type of access level each user have? (read, edit, fullcontrol)

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge there is no out of the box view to display all users and their permission levels. You can check each user's permission level one by one but that will be tedious.

With PowerShell: You can refer to this [link](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Access-Report-ac5e8235) to download User Permissions detail report for a Web Application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. i have updated GetUserAccessReport "http://spSserver" "c:\users_PermisionReport.csv" with my deatils. it does not work.
so i don"t have type my username and password

Comment: As indicated in the link, just update the following line: `GetUserAccessReport "http://spSserver" "c:\users_PermisionReport.csv"`. The first parameter is the URL of your webapplication and second is the path where the report is generated and saved.